# Universal "database" wrapper

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a universal system, particularly (but not definitely) in php. It's come down to values that don't simply point to other values being stored in mariadb (rather ideally), thus the thing is structurally sound and ready for scaling/etc. I figure before I get too deep in it I better ask (I haven't found anything out there that does this) if there's anything out there that does what this thing does.

So basically what I'm shooting for is something like an object that can be extended that is more or less just a wrapper for something like mysqli: the column definitions in the database need to have input filtration, such that filtering input is fully generalized (thats at least the idea). I figure there doesn't really need to be any output filtering, but the more the merrier.

I'm almost certain I'm not the first person to (attempt to) do this. :)

Thanks in advance for sharing your insights.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is `scaffolding`. Just google for `scaffolding php` and you'll find plenty of finished projects you could use or just take examples from.

Comment: Ok so maybe better yet, I figure that "variables" (requisite of logic) are "values", therefore perhaps a better question is: how well does php have everything panned out in terms of handling values? Any values? As far as I know it has it all covered, is this documented in the documentation anywhere? Anywhere you can point me towards? Thanks @dognose.

Comment: This sounds like an ORM to me?

Answer (score -1):

Ok so long story short, going all the way with this idea everything is accounted for in php, or can be handled (by custom coding).

--edit--

It's an orm, thanks @evert!

Comment: pdo...thank the heavens I'm not the first one to do this;)